# What is the proper way to extract expression used in v-for from template to component code

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to extract expression from the template which is inside `:class`:

```
<div
  v-for="(user, index) in users"
  :key="index"
  :class="{'bg-yellow-lighter': infoWindowMarker && 
  infoWindowMarker.position.lat === user.position.lat && 
  infoWindowMarker.position.lng === user.position.lng}"
>
// more HTML here
</div>
```

I have already thought about `computed` property and seems like I cannot use it as there is `v-for` looping over the array.

Is there any other way or maybe I can write a `method` and pass `user` to it?

Comment: Why would you want to extract anything there? It's already stripped down to the bare minimum. Also your question title wants to extract from `v-for`, whereas in your question body you ask to extract from `:class`. Can you please decide what you are asking for?

Comment: If you see the expression for `bg-yellow-lighter` is quite long and this is just an example. There may be more conditions there. I think putting more logic is a bad idea as I need to look into the template file.

Comment: Also I need to break the long line of code :)

Answer (score 1):

make a method like this:

```
methods:{
   getClass(user){
      return {'bg-yellow-lighter': infoWindowMarker && 
         infoWindowMarker.position.lat === user.position.lat && 
         infoWindowMarker.position.lng === user.position.lng}
   }
}
```

then your html would look like:

```
<div
  v-for="(user, index) in users"
  :key="index"
  :class="getClass(user)"
>
// more HTML here
</div>
```

note: if you need it to be reactive, you better make it computed property and not a method. more about it here:https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad